# Filter GeoJSON feed on a value in the path

Tags: 7, views, uri, feeds

I have GeoJSON feed, created with a view in Drupal 7, that I want to filter on a path value in the url of the loaded page (/path/%). The feed is loaded as an Openlayers map on a page. The feed seem to work with its own feed-url and is not aware of the site url. Contextual filters in the view don't work either. I can use hook_views_query_alter or hook_views_pre_view. But I don't know how to bring the value from my path into the hook function. Any suggestions or example code snippets?

I currently have this, but the url seems to be not recognized. How can I bring that in?

```
function Mymodule_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {    
  if ($view->name == 'My_view' && $view->current_display == 'My_display') {
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $basename = pathinfo($url_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $view->args[0] = $basename;
  }
}
```